# c++ armadillo modulus function

Tags: c++, modulus, armadillo

What is the **best way** to perform **modulus operator** over a **vector** or **matrix** in c++ **Armadillo**?

---

The vector and matrix classes overload the `%` operator to perform element-wise multiplication. Trying to use it yields an `invalid operands` error. **I was expecting** that

```
uvec a = {0, 1, 2, 3};
uvec b = a % 2;
cout << "b" << endl;
```

**would yield** the following:

```
b:
    0
    1
    0
    1
```

Comment: You'll have to do it element wise (e.g. in a loop).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operator '%' is for element-wise matrix multiplication. You have to create your own function:

```
/**
 * Extend division reminder to vectors
 *
 * @param   a       Dividend 
 * @param   n       Divisor
 */
template<typename T>
T mod(T a, int n)
{
    return a - floor(a/n)*n;
}
```

Comment: Nice idea---you should make note that it will require the use of `arma::floor` and specify that it requires armadillo vector types, not `std::vector`s.